# How to send post request with spring @RequestBody in rest client

Tags: spring, rest, post, firefox-addon

I have a class Person.

```
class Person{
Integer id;
String firstName;
String lastName;
//other params, constructors, getters & setters
}
```

& My method is

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public void testPerson(
            @RequestBody Person person){
...
}
```

Now I need to test it using rest client. I tried setting up “request header” section of the Firefox plugin to have a “name” = “Content-Type” and “value” = “application/x-www-form-urlencoded”
& then add parameters in body,

```
id=1&firstName=aaa&lastName=bbb
```

but it's giving 404.

Comment: You need to send a payload in json format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are getting `404` response, this means either your request URL is wrong or you using `GET` method instead of `POST` or vise versa.

Then regarding passing `Person` in request, if `@RequestBody` is used you have to pass JSON or XML in the body of the request as playload.

JSON:

```
{
  "id":1,
  "firstName":"aaa",
  "lastName":bbb
}
```

XML

```
<person>
  <id>1<id>
  <firstName>aaa</firstName>
  <lastName>bbb</lastName>  
</person>
```

Comment: I have added these 2 headers. Accept: application/json Content-Type: application/json & sent json request from body.

Comment: if you are using Jackson or other library to convert json to object . don't forget to add empty constructor to  object